# Создание экземпляра обобщенного типа C#

Tags: c#, generics

Есть метод со следующей сигнатурой:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(string predicate) where T : IDbModel;
```

Существует абстрактный класс (от которого в будущем будут наследоваться остальные классы), который реализует данный метод:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(string predicate) where T : IDbModel
{
    // do something

    //need to create instance of type T like this: T obj = new T()
}
```

Существует ли возможность создания объектов обобщенных типов?

p.s. Пишу очень-очень скромную версию *Eloquent ORM* как в Laravel

Comment: может быть, [эта ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731452/create-instance-of-generic-type) поможет?

Comment: Добавь constraint: `where T : IDbModel, new()`. [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, добавьте [constraint `new()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) на параметр генерика, и вы сможете создавать объекты через `new T()`:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(string predicate) where T : IDbModel, new()
{
    T obj = new T();
    // ...
}
```